# Having a integer number ID correlate to a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numbers

I want to have an ID number correlate to a string. Such as an ID is assigned to like `Bob` so if i either print the ID number or something like that, it will output `Bob` Sorry this doesn't give a lot of information, I can try to rephrase it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input: Use a python dictionary.

```
df = {'ID123':'Sponge',
      'ID111':'Bob',
      'ID222':'Square',
      'ID555':'Pants'}
```

Output: Enter the ID to get the answer which is Bob.

```
df['ID111']
```

Input: Add a new entry.

```
df['ID854'] = 'Gary'
```

Input: Delete an entry

```
del df['ID111']
```

Comment: So, If I have something that makes an ID. like `baseNumberID += 1` and i also have a script which gets the name. So I am able to generate an ID and Name, how would i go about making it so the ID and the name get added to it? Thanks.

P.S. if its not too much trouble, could you also tell me how i would remove something from the dictionary as well?

Comment: Try the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are after a dictionary,  an associative array data structure in Python:

```
k_v_dict = {'Bob': 1, 'Steven': 2,  'Larry': 3} 
print(k_v_dict.keys(), k_v_dict.values())
# Access by key: 
print(k_v_dict['Bob'], k_v_dict['Steven'], k_v_dict['Larry'])
# Unpack keys:
print({*{*k_v_dict}})
# Unpack keys 2: 
print({*{*k_v_dict.keys()}})
# Unpack values :
print({*{*k_v_dict.values()}})
```